# How do you validate if a property is accessible in php?

Tags: php, class, object, methods, properties

With classes containing private properties the property_exists() function returns true (php>5.3). With functions there is a method of is_callable that confirms not only the method exists but it is also available (as an alternative to method_exists()). Is there an equivalent counterpart to this function that will confirm if this property is accessible?

```
<?php

class testClass {

    private $locked;

    public $unlocked;

    private function hiddenFunction(){
        return "hidden";
    }

    public function visibleFunction(){
        return "visible";
    }

}

$object = new testClass();

var_dump(property_exists($object, "unlocked")); // returns true
var_dump(property_exists($object, "locked")); // returns true > php 5.3

var_dump(method_exists($object, "hiddenFunction")); // returns true but can't be called
var_dump(method_exists($object, "visibleFunction")); // returns true

var_dump(is_callable(array($object, "hiddenFunction"))); // returns false
var_dump(is_callable(array($object, "visibleFunction"))); // returns true

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Reflection](http://php.net/reflection) class taht will let you *reverse-engineer classes, interfaces, functions, methods and extensions*.

For example, to get all public properties of a class, you can do as follow :

```
$reflectionObject    = new ReflectionObject($object);
$testClassProperties = $reflectionObject->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
print_r ($testClassProperties);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ReflectionProperty Object
        (
            [name] => unlocked
            [class] => testClass
        )

)
```

to get all public methods of a class, you can do as follow :

```
$reflectionObject    = new ReflectionObject($object);
$testClassProperties = $reflectionObject->getMethods(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
print_r ($testClassProperties);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ReflectionMethod Object
        (
            [name] => visibleFunction
            [class] => testClass
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's odd that checking functions can be done with simple php functions but properties need to use the reflection class!

Comment: @Joe      <pre>  function isPublic($property, $object)
                 {
           $r_object    = new ReflectionObject($object);
           $properties = $r_object->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
        if (is_array($properties) && count($properties) >0) {
            foreach ($properties as $ppt) {
                if ($ppt->name == $property) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

         return false;
    }  </pre>